Virtual Console line overflow does not update after new GPU
Recently I upgrade my computer with a GeForce RTX 4060 and 64GB of memory from a GTX 960 and 16GB and noticed a nice performance increase in... at least Blender. However when I went to a tty / Virtual Console / CTRL+ALT+F1 I noticed that when I went beyond the height of the screen the text did not move up. I jumped back to desktop and back to the tty and the last lines showed up with the blinking cursor at the bottom. I pressed enter for a new line and the (wall of) text did not move and the blinking cursor vanished.
Running Debian 12, nvidia-driver-535.183.01, CUDA 12.2

Are you using the open source driver or the proprietary binary driver from Nvidia?

@Ramhound I just type in apt install nvidia-driver. My sources-list is set to bookworm main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

So the answer to my question is you are using the binary driver. Can you confirm?

@Ramhound How do I confirm this? What command do I type and what am I looking for specifically?
